# All scheduled notifications appear at once when restarting phone only on Android (Ionic framework)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications, localnotification

Here is my issue: Let's consider for example that I have a function that schedules a notification every week. So five weeks after having installed my app, I would have had 5 notifications that would have been displayed (one every week). Then, I restart my phone (for whatever reason) and all the notifications that had been displayed during those five weeks appear all in once. I don't understand how come that the previous scheduled notifications appear all in once when I restart my phone? (By the way, I cancel those notifications after they have been displayed). This problem only appears on ANDROID, the same app on IOS works perfectly. So, how come those notifications appear? It's like they are never completely cancelled? I tried several variants to avoid this problem but it doesn't want to go away. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

PS: I am using this plugin for local notifications: katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: Do all 5 appear at once, only after the scheduled time passed? Or say for example you schedule 5, restart the device immediately after, and then they all appear?

Comment: @NicRaboy Hello Nic, they all appear at once only after the scheduled time has passed. In other words, if the scheduled time has not passed and I restart the phone, nothing will appear. In fact, if I scheduled 5 notifications, only the ones for which the scheduled time has passed will be displayed when the device is restarted. So if for the 5 scheduled notifications, the scheduled time is passed only for 3 of them. Then when I'll restart the phone only 3 notifications will appear at once.

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but it kind of sounds like that should be the expected behavior.  When my Android phone dies and I boot it up 12 hours later after charging it, I end up with massive amounts of notifications.  Always figured it was normal.  Maybe iOS just does things differently.

Comment: But If The notification was canceled before the device was shut down, when you boot it up the notification shouldn't appear. Am I wrong on this ?

Comment: Well, I could formulate the problem in another way: I want my notification to be canceled after a few seconds even when the app is closed. How could I do that? Apparently the problem is that the notification never canceled so how could I programmatically schedule a notification and say "cancel yourself after 30 seconds"?

Comment: You don't.  Cordova apps don't play nice in the background so you would need to call cancel using the ID you used when you scheduled it in the foreground. https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples#cancel-notifications

Comment: That's what I have done. But if I understand you correctly, if I do not open the app, The "cancel" will not trigger? Here is the last scenario I will bother you with: 1) the user opens the app. 2) the notification get scheduled for tomorrow. 3) the user closes the app. 3) the next day, he gets the notification correctly BUT it doesn't cancels because for the notification to be canceled he has to reopen the app in order for the "notification.cancel" to act. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer.

iOS cancels the notifications after they have been triggered. Android does not. Therefore, if the users opens the app, let's say you have scheduled a notification to appear in two days, and then close it and don't reopen it, two days later he will get the notification as scheduled. But, if he never reopens the app, that notification will never be canceled on Android and the notification will re-appear every time you restart your phone. To be cancelled, the user has to reopen the app for the bit of code that you've written to cancel the notification could run. It is very annoying because the purpose of a notification (in my case at least) is to allow the user to get an information without opening the app. Fortunately on iOs, the notifications cancels themselves so it works perfectly.

Thanks to Nic Raboy fr his time and help.

Comment: Yea Android can be a little weird with notifications.  Glad you got it :-)